# How to get a basic kraken-js app running on heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to host the default app that comes when setting up a barebones kraken-js app on heroku and I am getting the following errors:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web dynos... done, now running 1


$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): `node index.js`
web.1: crashed 2013/12/01 17:35:26 (~ 4m ago)


$ heroku logs
2013-12-02T01:07:09+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-12-02T01:07:33+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-12-02T01:07:38.678103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2013-12-02T01:07:39.524560+00:00 app[web.1]: [TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings]
2013-12-02T01:07:40.563355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-12-02T01:07:40.607963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-12-02T01:07:40.609066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-12-02T01:07:43.067843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2013-12-02T01:07:44.542123+00:00 app[web.1]: [TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings]
2013-12-02T01:07:45.675718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-12-02T01:07:45.706079+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-12-02T01:07:55.027410+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by [**email@address.com**]
2013-12-02T01:07:32.834177+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by [**email@address.com**]
2013-12-02T01:07:32.869073+00:00 heroku[api]: Add PATH config by [**email@address.com**]
2013-12-02T01:07:32.902126+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by [**email@address.com**]
2013-12-02T01:07:32.970126+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 108a492 by [**email@address.com**]
2013-12-02T01:07:33.003919+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by [**email@address.com**]
2013-12-02T01:09:46.242570+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by [**email@address.com**]
2013-12-02T01:09:51.867085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=shrouded-thicket-6905.herokuapp.com fwd="24.87.73.5" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-12-02T01:09:52.551619+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=shrouded-thicket-6905.herokuapp.com fwd="24.87.73.5" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-12-02T01:16:30.083346+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=shrouded-thicket-6905.herokuapp.com fwd="24.87.73.5" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-12-02T01:16:29.843983+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=shrouded-thicket-6905.herokuapp.com fwd="24.87.73.5" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I have a Procfile with the following line 
    web: node index.js
with the command to be executed to start a web dyno.

This simple app works on my local env when I use
    foreman start 
I can browse the hello world page by going to 
    localhost:5000

Is there something I need to configure differently?
Here is the default package.json

```
{
  "name": "kraken",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "prototype",
  "author": "laura cabrera",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "kraken-js": "~0.6.1",
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "adaro": "~0.1.x",
    "nconf": "~0.6.8",
    "less": "~1.3.3",
    "dustjs-linkedin": "~2.0.3",
    "dustjs-helpers": "~1.1.1",
    "makara": "~0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "~1.10.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-dustjs": "~1.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.4",
    "grunt-mocha-cli": "~1.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm also playing with this. I was able to login to the console and do the steps for a fresh install with yo generator-kraken and that worked, by my own repo push does not work

Comment: Also I get this error when trying to run `node index.js` from the Heroku console: [TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings]

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed as of Kraken v0.7.0

No special action required!

Answer (score 0):

I filed a bug with Kraken for this:

https://github.com/paypal/kraken-js/issues/43